# "Unattach" WAR artifact from lifecycle since it's is superseded by an RPM

Tags: maven

We have a multi-module Maven project who's primary artifact is a WAR.  However our final build step is RPM packaging of that said WAR, and we really don't *care* about the WAR itself from a distributionManagement perspective.  I would still like the JARS/source-jars uploaded to our Nexus repository, but it's just wasteful in terms of time/space to upload the WARs since no-one links agains that.

I would like to mark the WAR plugin as 'ignored' from a build life cycle point of view when going through the 'deploy' phase, since the RPM bundle itself is used.

I can't see any plugin configuration of the WAR plugin to avoid this, has anyone got any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that what the [primaryArtifact property](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#primaryArtifact) does? I've never used it, but I always assumed that's what it was for.